# bash remove a variable prefix from filename

Tags: bash, rename, prefix

I have some files with this format for the filename: `<timestamp>-High<variable alphanumeric string>`, for instance `2016-10-01 11:12:12-Highlaskdja`.

I am trying to rename all those file removing the timestamp prefix.
I have tried with the following, but it does not work

```
#!/bin/bash
latest=$(ls -dt ~/old/* | head -3) #actually I am removing the 3 most recent files, the error is not here
for file in $latest; do
    fileString = "$file"
    target = ${fileString%High*}
    echo $target #I got error before this line so I have not written any "mv"
done
```

How can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: No spaces around `=` in bash assignment.

Comment: FUUUUUCKKKKKKKK!

Comment: @choroba thank you! Actually I had to use `target = High${file#*High}` and to remove those damned whitespaces.